# javascript textbox date mask without jquery or a plugin

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a simple textbox date mask 'mm/dd/yy" function for javascript. I need it NOT to be jquery dependent or any other type of plugin.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Getting the input events (a lib could really help), validating against your mask, or feedback the result of the check?

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateDate(date) { 
    var re = /^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](\d\d)$/;
    return re.test(date);
}
```